# Creating JSON - part loop, part plain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the below code, which loops through the DOM looking for elements that have an id starting with "sale-", with an attribute "data-id", capturing the value, then stripping the opening and closing square brackets - pushing it all into a JSON object:

```
els = $("div[id^='sale-']");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
var id = el.attributes[2].value.replace(/\[|\]/gi, "");

var jsonObject = {"id" :+id};

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
console.log(myJSON+",")
});
```

This works and the output is:

[image]

Now the problem comes when I want to apply some static JSON code before and after the loop.

I would like something like the below:

```
// static
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'impressions': [

// loop portion
{"id":50450},
{"id":49877},
{"id":49848}, 
{"id":49912},
{"id":49860},
{"id":49825}, 
{"id":48291}, 
{"id":49667},

// static
]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you can make the array creation much more simple by calling `map()` on the jQuery object. From there you can simply add the resulting array to an object with the required structure. Try this:

```
var idArr = $("div[id^='sale-']").map(function() {
  var id = this.attributes[2].value.replace(/\[|\]/gi, "");
  return { id: +id };
}).get();

dataLayer.push({
  ecommerce: {
    impressions: idArr
  }
});
```

Also note that `this.attributes[2].value` can be improved, but you haven't stated which attribute you're expecting that to target.